# Including a content page inside an AEM component

Tags: aem, sightly

How to display a page which is inside /content/proj/en inside a component.Given that the page will be available in all the environments.

Comment: What do you mean by displaying a page? Are you looking to render a page? Page has head/body tags so rendering it inside a component is not going to work unless you use an IFRAME.

Comment: Do you want to embed a page in component? Or do you want to render a content/page(AEM page) inside a component as a sub page? What are you looking for can you provide your use case?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way, you can do a sling include.

If you are using JSP

```
<sling:include path="/content/proj/en/jcr:content" />
```

If you are using HTL

```
<sly data-sly-resource="${'/content/proj/en/jcr:content' @ wcmmode=disabled}"></sly>
```

You can remove the wcmmode=disabled if you want the rendered resource to be editable.